# HashMap contains 4 elements but only 3 are shown in debug

Tags: java, hashmap

I have defined an `HashMap` with the following code:

```
final Map<OrderItemEntity, OrderItemEntity> savedOrderItems = new HashMap<OrderItemEntity, OrderItemEntity>();
final ListIterator<DiscreteOrderItemEntity> li = ((BundleOrderItemEntity) oi).getDiscreteOrderItems().listIterator();

while (li.hasNext()) {
    final DiscreteOrderItemEntity doi = li.next();
    final DiscreteOrderItemEntity savedDoi = (DiscreteOrderItemEntity) orderItemService.saveOrderItem(doi);
    savedOrderItems.put(doi, savedDoi);
    li.remove();
}

((BundleOrderItemEntity) oi).getDiscreteOrderItems().addAll(doisToAdd);
final BundleOrderItemEntity savedBoi = (BundleOrderItemEntity) orderItemService.saveOrderItem(oi);
savedOrderItems.put(oi, savedBoi);
```

I put 4 items into the `HashMap`. When I debug, even if the `size` is 4, it only shows 3 elements:

[image: debugging session]

This is the list of the elements it contains.

```
{DiscreteOrderItemEntity@1c29ef3c=DiscreteOrderItemEntity@41949d95, DiscreteOrderItemEntity@2288b93c=DiscreteOrderItemEntity@2288b93c, BundleOrderItemEntity@1b500292=BundleOrderItemEntity@d0f29ce5, DiscreteOrderItemEntity@9203174a=DiscreteOrderItemEntity@9203174a}
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Um, I see 4 elements in the string representation. How are you only seeing 3?

Comment: Yes string representation is 4 but under table you can see only 3. When i try to get the value for BundleOrderItemEntity@1b500292 key... I get NULL in return.

Comment: Ah, I see - have you expanded all of those nodes? Basically you'll find one of them links to another...

Comment: Yes i did but the fourth one BundleOrderItemEntity@1b500292 is not present anywhere. I kept on clicking sub trees also.

Comment: Well it clearly *is* present somewhere - it's not like the code is going to make it up when you call `toString`. You probably just need to explore the nodes more thoroughly.

Comment: I see.. thanks for the info. I will dig more deeper. But the question is why i get null when i try to have map.get(Object key)

Comment: You mean savedOrderItems.get(oi) is returning null?

Comment: If that was the question you wanted to ask, you should have mentioned it *in the question*, along with a short but complete example demonstrating the problem. I suspect the problem is with your equals or hashCode implementation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Hashmaps handle collisions*.

Since your `HashMap` is composed by only 16 buckets, the hash of the element must be reduced to a number that spans between *0* and *15* (e.g. `hash % 16`). So two elements may be in the same bucket (the same `HashMapNode`).

You can inspect each `HashMapNode` to find out which one contains two elements.

Comment: Good direction enrico. I will try to dig more. Nice problem to enrich my hashmap understanding.

Comment: @SaurabhKumar your're welcome. Check for example [here](http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2013/08/hashing-how-hash-map-works-in-java-or.html).

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism is explained as enrico.bacis, There is an example to reproduce it:

```
public class TestJava {
    static class TT {
        private String field;
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<TT, String> test = new HashMap<>();
        TT t1 = new TT();
        TT t2 = new TT();
        test.put(t1, "test2");
        test.put(t2, "test2");
        test.put(null, "test2");
        test.put(null, "test2");

        System.out.println(test.toString());
        System.out.println(test.size());
    }
}
```

In there we override `hashCode` and hard code return ***1*** that all objects of `TT` will return same hashCode ***1***.

and we can dig into `HashMap.java`:

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    return putVal(hash(key), key, value, false, true);
}

static final int hash(Object key) {
    int h;
    return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
}
final V putVal(int hash, K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent,
               boolean evict) {
```

we can found when we put key/value pair into `HashMap`, it will calculate `hash number` by object's hashcode to locate the element's location in hash table.

so if the objects hash code are same, they will be stored in the same bucket in hash table. but these confilct elements still will be stored, because their key are not same.